# How make a one and the same www root folder in Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have 2 instances in **different** zones, and I want make for they same www root folder. How I can do this?

ps EBS could attached just for one zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Amazon VPS to manage your servers across different availability zones, I guess you could use NFS to mount a common doc root across all your instances running your webservers  (assuming you're running Linux).

So basically after you have setup NFS, mount the directory on your individual EC2 instances running httpd and point the docroot to the mounted directory.

See http://www.migrate2cloud.com/blog/how-to-setup-nfs-server-on-aws-ec2 to get an idea of what this would entail.

I have not personally attempted this myself so take what I said with a grain of Na2Cl